# Redirecting from "www" to root domain in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

I have a fairly simple task, but it doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out the reason for it. I have a digitalocean droplet and a domain that points to the digitalocean dns. I have set up an "A Record" with "@" and "www" for the domain that both point to my droplet. In my nginx config I have set up one server block for the redirect which contains:

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Now when I do:

```
curl -I http://www.example.com
```

I get a http response saying "301 permanently moved" with the correct location. (When I use https I don't get the "permanently moved" but that's a different story).

However when I open the URL in my browser nothing happens and I just get the default nginx website.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Its correct, you just need a nginx server listening on example.com :

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
         # do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I ommitted this part to make it shorter, but I actually do have another block listening to example.com.

Comment: If curl return 301 with the good address, its probably the server block listening on  example.com wich is wrong. Otherwise maybe the response is just still cached by the browser. Have you the nginx error page when you do curl -L http://www.example.com

Comment: Somehow it worked now, but unfortunately I'm not entirely sure as to why. I recreated ssl certificats for both the host and www (using certbot). Certbot then added a "listen 443 ssl" section to my server-block for www.example.com, after that it worked. Makes no real sense to me, but well.

Anyways... I appreciate your help!